# On Adsense reports, where can I see the pages of my website on which Ads where clicked?

Tags: google-adsense, advertising

On Adsense reports, where can I see the pages of my website on which Ads where clicked? I'd like to compare CTR, CPM, on a page-by-page basis or at least depending on the type of page (review, blog post, etc.)

How could I find that?

Answer (score 1):

To view your AdSense revenue, navigate to Behavior » Publisher » Overview. This gives you a quick summary of ways your AdSense advertisements are performing. Besides that, you may also view other reviews in Google Analytics.

Comment: _How_ can they enable AdSense reports to be viewable in Google Analytics?

Comment: By going to Insights » Settings » Publisher, then navigate to Ads tracking & enable the Google AdSense tracking.

Answer (score 0):

You can view your ad stats by page type by grouping your ads into channels.    If your page types are each in their own directory (eg. `http://example.com/blog-posts/...`) then you can [create URL channels](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/10075505#create_a_URL_channel) for each type.   Otherwise you will need to [create custom channels](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/10078316#create_a_custom_channel) which involves putting separate JavaScript for ads on each page type.

If there is some specific specific page that you want to see stats for, you can create a URL channel just for that page.   You won't be able to do that for all your pages because Google limits the number of channels that each AdSense account has.